# Rules for how Drush vset works

Tags: drush

I want to perform some admin configurations through drush using vset the way I've used it in the past, such as the following:

```
drush vset site_name Example;

drush vset site_offline 1;

drush vset preprocess_css;
```

If I wanted to turn off email varification on the following page, is there a variable I can use drush vset to set the variable to 0 or 1?

admin/config/people/accounts

If so, how would I find the variable names for admin configurations to know which ones can be set by drush?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On administration forms system_settings_form is normally used to return form,
so the element id is same as the variable name without the "#edit-" with underscores.

For example on: /admin/config/system/site-information

```
id="edit-site-mail" -> drush vset site_mail peter@email.com
```

To turn off the email verification:

```
"edit-user-email-verification" -> drush vset user_email_verification 1
```

Drush returns all variables that match with your variable name, so if you only know part of the name you can try:

```
drush vget email
```

returns all matches:

```
user_mail_status_canceled_notify: 0
user_mail_status_canceled_subject: "Account details for [user:name] at [site:name] (canceled)"
reroute_email_address: "debug@email.net"
reroute_email_enable: "TRUE"
```

Module devel (https://drupal.org/project/devel) let you check all drupal variables on this menu callback: /devel/variable